# Passando ID por parametro no modal

Tags: php, html, button

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho um `$Id` PHP que preciso receber ele no modal para fazer um `SELECT` na tabela, e buscar informações no BD.

O botão ele fica em uma página, e o modal em outra, e fiz o include para poder chamar o modal, quando clico no botão ele não passa o $Id.

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalDetalhes" data-id="<?php echo $Id; ?>">
    <img src="Imagens/Detalhes.png" width="36" height="20">
</button>
```

---

Vou tentar postar minha linha de codigo para mostrar meu problema:

```
Arquivo OrdermServico.php

<?php
include("All_Modals");
$Busca = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM OrdemServico WHERE Status ='$Status'", $con -> conexaoMysqlP()) or die (mysql_error());
    $ContCampos = mysql_num_rows($Busca);
        $Consulta = mysql_fetch_array($Busca);
?>
<?php
if($ContCampos > 0) {
    do {
?>
<table>
<tr>
<td width="130px"><?=$Consulta["Status"]?></td>
<td width="380px"><?=@$Consulta["LaudoTecnico"] ?></td>
<td width="115px" align="center">
aqui preciso pegar o $ID 
    <?php 
    $Id = $Consulta["id"];
     ?>
<a href="" data-target="#ModalDetalhes" data-toggle="modal">Abrir Modal</a>

    </td>
</tr> 
</table>    
<?php
}while ($Consulta = mysql_fetch_assoc($Busca));

}
?>
```

Arquivo All_Modals.php

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalDetalhes" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <?php
    //Aqui preciso receber a variavel php para usar no select

    echo $Id;
        // Seleciona tabela o id para editar, excluir ou etc
            $query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM OrdemServico WHERE id = '$Id'", $con -> conexaoMysqlP()) or die (mysql_error());
                $Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1);
                    $row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);

        <div class="form-inline">  
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>OS Detalhes</label>
            </div>     
<div class="modal-body">
<php //Aqui irei montar o restante do codigo php ?>
<div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="BotaoEnviar">      
  </div>
</form>      
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: É Bootstrap? Isso deveria funcionar, estás a passar a variável direita? Tem o mesmo nome? Vi em cima `$id` e depois `$Id`. As vezes acontecem coisas dessas ;)

Comment: É sim, Não e direto não, o button do modal tenho em uma página, e o modal em outra, ai chamei com o include... o modal abre, mas não consigo passar o valor do $Id através do data-id="<?php echo $Id; ?>"

Comment: É isto que queres? http://jsfiddle.net/k7FC2/1440/

Comment: Show amigo, deu certo, porém necessito de uma variável php, pois preciso fazer um select no modal, tipo se possível no js o  <input type="text" name="bookId" value=""/> fosse a variavel, infelizmente estou começando agora e sou leigo com JS... e o php domino bem já!

Comment: Usa $_session. E zera quando terminar o código.

Comment: @JorgeB. seu exemplo deu certo em parte, porém no modal exibi o id corretamente, porém preciso que o <input[name="bookId">  receba via php, por exemplo: $Id ='<input type="text" name="bookId" value=""/>';, mas não funciona rsrs, poderia me dar mais um help? Pois ali no modal vou fazer mais um select, para filtrar e exibir os dados desse $Id. Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marcos,

Para fazer esse tipo de chamada eu normalmente uso um modal buscando a URL de forma remota, assim já passo o parametro pela URL direto, como abaixo:

```
<a data-target="#remoteModal" data-toggle="modal" href="http://www.site.com.br/arquivoRemoto.php?variavel=parametro" class="btn btn-nav active" type="button">
ABRIR MODAL
</a>
```

Comment: Eu tentei amigo, mais no modal não consigo receber ela, tentei mais não vai, exemplo: $Var = $_GET['variavel']; fiz assim mais obtive não tive sucesso.

Comment: Tenta colocar online um modelo para eu poder te auxiliar, pois é bem simples passar o parâmetro direto pela url, ou no exemplo que o amigo, Jorge B comentou com um exemplo no jsfiddle caso queira recuperar por javascript mesmo.

Comment: Tente então guardar em um $_session.